# Timer Count Down with UIDatePicker doesnot firing datePickerValue for 1st time and also in my datePicker hour is showing like ho... and for min

Tags: swift

when I select picker for first time datePickerValueChanged is not getting called. however for next time it is working fine and hour and minute is not showing completely and one more thing i want to hide picker when tapping outside of textField, it is working but when i tapping on button also pickerview is hiding which i don't want and is it possible to hide pickerview on second tap of text field means i want to open and hide pickerview on the touch of textField. Here is my code..

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            super.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
            self.timeTF.delegate = self
            self.picker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
            self.picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
            self.picker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
            self.picker.countDownDuration = 60 * 30
            self.timeTF.rightView = rightButtonView
            self.timeTF.rightViewMode = .always
        }

      @objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker){
            let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
            let selectedDate: String = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
            timeTF.text = selectedDate
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: sender.date)
            if let hour = components.hour, let minute = components.minute {
                let timeString = String(format: "%02ld:%02ld", hour, minute)
                self.timeTF.text = timeString
                self.viewModel.hour = hour
                self.viewModel.minute = minute
                self.totalTime()

            }
        }

// Hide keyboard when touch outside
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: Can you share any demo project where we can replicate same?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time and try to add enough information to the question so that the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: you can check my demo project here.
 https://gofile.io/?c=t0YvQV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i solved my problem.. in count down timer hour and minute was shrinking because of custom font. and for text field

```
 var showDatePicker = false

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            if textField == timeTF {
             self.refresh()
            }
            return false
        }

        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            if textField == timeTF {
             textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }

    @IBAction func refresh() {
            if showPicker == true {
                self.datePickerHeightConstraint.constant = 0
                rightButtonView.setImage(UIImage(named: "dissmiss-lite.png"), for: .normal)
            } else {
                self.datePickerHeightConstraint.constant = 216
                rightButtonView.setImage(UIImage(named: "open-lite.png"), for: .normal)
            }
            self.showPicker = !self.showPicker

        }
```

when i tap on textfield it will open datepicker and again i tap it will hide date picker and according it will change image of textfield button.